# Why is the third person singular used instead of third person plural in here:

Tags: verb, grammatical-number

While the context and even the image in Studio D A1 implies that there are a couple of people, but it's written as:

> Die Polizei ist gekommen.

instead of

> Die Polizei sind gekommen.

and somewhere else it's indicated as:

> Sie (die Polizei) haben ein protokoll geschreiben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Die Polizei ist gekommen.

That's because *die Polizei* ist a collective singular noun as *das Geld*, *das Mehl*, *der Zucker*.

This is different from the noun *der Polizist/die Polizistin* which aren't collectives.

> Sie (die Polizei) **hat** ein Protokoll geschrieben.
>
> Sie (die Polizisten/Polizistinnen) **haben** ein Protokoll geschrieben.

Sometimes, *die Polizei* is used in plural:

> Die Polizeien Deutschlands und der Niederlande haben bei dieser Drogenrazzia eng zusammengearbeitet.

Comment: Yeah!! Now I do understand! The second sentence it says "Sie haben ..." but actually it refers to Polizisten/Polizistinnen not the Collective singular noun which is "Polizei" in here. Thanks a lot dear @Janka

Comment: Is really *Polizei* a collective noun? (And is it Zucker?)

Comment: I'd think so. It applies to any individual associated with it.

Comment: The source of confusion is probably that the English language addresses an *organization* consisting of several people in the plural form (the police *are* doing something) while German regards the organization as a single entity and thus uses singular here.